# Convert 5-mins intraday price to daily price

Tags: r, price

I'm seeking guidance from R expert
I have a data frame of 5-mins intraday prices and want to convert into daily price, how should I do it? I've searched the package "highfrequency" and attempted to use aggregatets function but it was to no avail
here is my data sample

```
  DT     Open     High      Low    Close Volume
1: 1991-01-02 07:25:00   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000      0
2: 1991-01-02 07:30:00 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594      0
3: 1991-01-02 07:35:00 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594      0
4: 1991-01-02 07:40:00 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594      0
5: 1991-01-02 07:45:00 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594 101.3594      0
6: 1991-01-02 07:50:00 101.3750 101.3750 101.3750 101.3750      0
```

Comment: Post some actual data

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add my data, already fixed it

Comment: How is the "daily price" calculated? The mean price, the last price, the highest price, ...? If you want help you need to help the potential helpers

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us your details so I'll guess how you have it organized.

So for starters we will make a table with variables `data` - value from `FirstDay` every 5 minutes in `n` periods), `product` - three different products, `price` - with different mean and sd for each product.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

FirstDay = dmy_hm("01/01/2021 00:00")
n=3000

df = tibble(
  date = rep(FirstDay+5*60*1:n, each = 3),
  product = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = n),
  price = c(rnorm(n, 100, 20), rnorm(n, 200, 20), rnorm(n, 50, 10)))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 9,000 x 3
   date                product price
   <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01 00:05:00 A       119. 
 2 2021-01-01 00:05:00 A        81.3
 3 2021-01-01 00:05:00 A        75.6
 4 2021-01-01 00:10:00 A        81.0
 5 2021-01-01 00:10:00 A       105. 
 6 2021-01-01 00:10:00 A       132. 
 7 2021-01-01 00:15:00 A        80.8
 8 2021-01-01 00:15:00 A       108. 
 9 2021-01-01 00:15:00 A        94.6
10 2021-01-01 00:20:00 A        77.0
# ... with 8,990 more rows
```

Now for a simple summary

```
df %>% group_by(product, date(date)) %>% 
  summarise(mprice = mean(price))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   product [3]
   product `date(date)` mprice
   <chr>   <date>        <dbl>
 1 A       2021-01-01     99.4
 2 A       2021-01-02    100. 
 3 A       2021-01-03     99.8
 4 A       2021-01-04    101. 
 5 B       2021-01-04    200. 
 6 B       2021-01-05    200. 
 7 B       2021-01-06    199. 
 8 B       2021-01-07    200. 
 9 C       2021-01-07     49.1
10 C       2021-01-08     50.3
11 C       2021-01-09     50.3
12 C       2021-01-10     50.3
13 C       2021-01-11     50.3
```

**Update 1**

Okay, now that you have added a sample of your data, we can do it again.

First, let me prepare a little more data. Don't worry if you don't understand something here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
ndays = 40
FirstDay = ymd_hm("1991-01-01 00:00")

df = tibble(
  DT = FirstDay+(5*60)*1:(ndays*24*60/5),
  Open = rnorm(length(DT), 100, 2) + 
    (as.numeric(date(DT)) - 7670)*2,
  High = Open + rnorm(1, 10, 1),
  Low = Open - rnorm(1, 10, 1),
  Close = lag(Open),
  Volume = rnorm(length(DT), 1000, 100))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 11,520 x 6
   DT                   Open  High   Low Close Volume
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1991-01-01 00:05:00  98.8  108.  88.6  NA     996.
 2 1991-01-01 00:10:00  96.4  106.  86.1  98.8  1028.
 3 1991-01-01 00:15:00  98.0  108.  87.8  96.4   943.
 4 1991-01-01 00:20:00  99.6  109.  89.3  98.0  1005.
 5 1991-01-01 00:25:00 103.   112.  92.3  99.6   904.
 6 1991-01-01 00:30:00  96.4  106.  86.1 103.   1173.
 7 1991-01-01 00:35:00 102.   111.  91.5  96.4  1131.
 8 1991-01-01 00:40:00  98.8  108.  88.5 102.   1051.
 9 1991-01-01 00:45:00  97.8  107.  87.5  98.8  1113.
10 1991-01-01 00:50:00  97.7  107.  87.5  97.8   888.
# ... with 11,510 more rows
```

As you can see, I generated data for 40 days.

Now we can summarize it. However, I don't know anything about how you want to calculate the daily price. For this, I consider several different values such as open price, closing price, highest price, lowest price for each day.

```
df %>% group_by(date(DT)) %>% 
  summarise(
    Open = Open[1],
    High = max(High),
    Low = min(Low),
    Close = Close[length(Close)],
    Mean = (Close - Open)/2
  )
```

output

```
# A tibble: 41 x 6
   `date(DT)`  Open  High   Low Close    Mean
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 1991-01-01  98.8  115.  84.2 101.   1.10  
 2 1991-01-02 101.   118.  86.4 101.  -0.0101
 3 1991-01-03 103.   119.  89.2  99.5 -1.55  
 4 1991-01-04 107.   121.  87.2 106.  -0.260 
 5 1991-01-05 107.   124.  90.7 106.  -0.714 
 6 1991-01-06 110.   124.  92.6 112.   1.07  
 7 1991-01-07 110.   127.  94.5 109.  -0.526 
 8 1991-01-08 114.   129.  98.1 113.  -0.463 
 9 1991-01-09 115.   132. 101.  117.   1.00  
10 1991-01-10 118.   133. 102.  118.   0.364 
# ... with 31 more rows
```

If you need other values, modify this summary yourself. This shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

unless it is a school homework, why dont you just import the data in daily intervals?

```
#install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod) 

getSymbols(Symbols = c("BTC-USD"),
           from = from,
           to = to,
           src = "yahoo",
           adjust = TRUE,
           periodicity = "daily") #set the period
```

Comment: Thanks I can easily import daily price, however what I need to do is to calculate daily price from intraday prices